# How can I find common rows between two dataframes based on two different numeric columns?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have two different data frames that I want to find common rows between them according to two different numeric columns (these columns are the location of the genes in genome, start and end), but I don't want to be completely match based on those two columns and I want to find commons with (-+) ranges.

Actually I want to find common rows even they are with for example 200 bp or 500 bp differences in start and end locations. I am beginner in R and I could not find a way to do this.

In df2 although DEC1 has different START location but its difference is 400 bp with DEC1 in df1, so i want to consider this gene as a common between df1 and 2 but PSA and AKT have difference in START more than 500bp and I do not need them, although they have same END position between df1 and 2.

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("DEC1", "PSA", "DEC2", "AKT"), START = c("9494957", "39689186", "89435677", "78484829"), END = c("52521320", "114050940", "100952138", "78486308"), STRAND = c("+", "+", "+", "-"))
```

```
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("DEC1", "PSA", "DEC2", "AKT"), START = c("9494557", "37689186", "89435677", "79484829"), END = c("52521320", "114050940", "100952138", "78486308"), STRAND = c("+", "+", "+", "-"))
```

Comment: I would advise checking out ``bedtools`` or the [equivalent R library](https://github.com/PhanstielLab/bedtoolsr) or perhaps ``data.table::foverlaps``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, `merge` or `join` would be the only way to compare two columns.

Using `data.table`,

```r
require(data.table)
#> Loading required package: data.table
df1 <- setDT(data.frame(name = c("DEC1", "PSA", "DEC2", "AKT"), START = c(9494957, 39689186, 89435677, 78484829), END = c(52521320, 114050940, 100952138, 78486308), STRAND = c("+", "+", "+", "-")))
df2 <- setDT(data.frame(name = c("DEC1", "PSA", "DEC2", "AKT"), START = c(9494557, 37689186, 89435677, 79484829), END = c(52521320, 114050940, 100952138, 78486308), STRAND = c("+", "+", "+", "-")))
df3 <- df1[df2[,.(name,START2=START, END2 = END)], on='name']

df3[abs(START2-START) %between% c(0,500) |
      abs(START2-START) %between% c(0,500)]
```

```
#>    name    START       END STRAND   START2      END2
#> 1: DEC1  9494957  52521320      +  9494557  52521320
#> 2: DEC2 89435677 100952138      + 89435677 100952138
```

Or using `dplyr`,

```
df3 <- inner_join(df1, df2, suffix=c('1','2'),by='name')
df3 %>% filter(abs(START2-START1)<500)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: the code that you mentioned is not what I need, As I said I want genes that are common based on START and END columns, but it is not necessary to be completely match and a little difference in START or END is acceptable. Like DEC1 that its START location in df1 and df2 has 400 bp difference. So, arrange of diffenece between df1 and df2 for column START and END is possible like -+ 500bp. Therefore, I want output DEC1 and DEC2 because just these two are same and maximum with 500 bp difference.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I edited the answer. Please check it out.